# Android: change titlebar on checkbox click

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, titlebar

I have an activity with a **RelativeLayout** consisting of a **ListView**. This ListView is populated through a custom **ListAdapter**. The list displays a checkbox and text for each row.
So far, so good.

I want to implement something like the default android Gmail app, where if I checkbox-select an email, the titlebar of the application at the top changes and presents options relevant to the selection (such as delete, move, archive, etc). I am not sure what to look for in the Android documentation.

Do I just create some layout above the ListView and dynamically add elements(like delete row, etc) to it on a checkbox click? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `Do I just create some layout above the ListView and dynamically add elements(like delete row, etc) to it on a checkbox click?`. Yes, this will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

if you have used **ActionBarSherlock**  then you can use **Action mode** menu to show various option to user when checkbox is selected from listview

or 
you can try

http://java.dzone.com/articles/contextual-action-bar-cab

Comment: Thanks, but I would rather stick to the default/native Android elements :)

Comment: if you want use action mode from native then they need android API Version 11